# How to extends interface from type as optional?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

As following, how can I create a interface with all /*Student*/ type and partial /*School*/ and make sure gender is required for Peter and is optional for Student?

```
export type School = {
  address: string;
  state: string;
};
export type Gender = { gender: boolean};
export type Human = {first: string; last: string};

export interface Student extends Gender, Human{};
//I want Gender as optional for Student

export interface Peter extends Student, Pick<School, 'address'>, Gender {};
//I want Gender as required for Peter
```

Comment: `interface Student extends Partial<Gender>, Human {}` should work.

Comment: consider not using a boolean value for gender. Life is more complicated than that, and there's good guides out there for being more inclusive. Usually 4 values greatly increase your cover (`F`, `M`, `O`, `U`). other and unknown are the last 2.

Comment: @kaya3 no it does not work. I have error for `Interface 'Peter' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Student' and 'Gender'.
  Named property 'gender' of types 'Student' and 'Gender' are not identical.` because Peter need to extends from Student as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want `Student` to extend `Partial<Gender>` and not `Gender`.  The subsequent error is a safety net to prevent you from inheriting possibly unrelated types for the same property.  The simplest way to get this error to go away is to explicitly add the property mentioned so that the compiler doesn't have to worry about it:

```
export interface Student extends Partial<Gender>, Human { };

export interface Peter extends Student, Pick<School, 'address'>, Gender {
  gender: boolean; // okay
};
```

---

Another way to do this without being redundant is to use [intersections](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) instead of `extends`.  They are very similar: if `A extends B, C` is true then `A extends B & C` should also be true.  Unfortunately, syntax restrictions prevent `implements` or `extends` clauses in type declarations to be general type expressions.  They need to be actual named types with statically known property names:

```
export interface Student extends Partial<Gender>, Human { };

export interface Peter extends Pick<School, 'address'>, (Student & Gender) { }; // error!
//  --------------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.
```

Luckily, since `Student & Gender` is a type with statically known properties, all that's missing is a name.  Let's give it one:

```
export type GenderedStudent = Student & Gender;
export interface Peter extends Pick<School, 'address'>, GenderedStudent { }; // okay
```

Now that works.

---

In both cases you have a `Student` as not requiring a `Gender`, but a `Peter` (weird, a whole interface for people whose name is "Peter"?) does require one:

```
const s: Student = {
  first: "Harry",
  last: "Potter"
}; // okay

const p: Peter = {
  first: "Peter",
  last: "Pettigrew",
  address: "Gryffindor House, Hogwarts",
  gender: true // it is true that Peter has a gender
}; // okay

const badP: Peter = {
  first: "Peter",
  last: "Pettigrew",
  address: "Ron Weasley's pocket",      
}; // error, gender is missing
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJKiSwLICiAHjBgJbyMAuACgE4D2MEnrAJ54SpJBHrcBSIXyQBleAAtu3DEgC8IwmLEgAJvs7QoALiRRWnRsADmAblG7LIVhHOXrdxzrEBfH10JGClWGUE5AHEIYH1+TTwkWxi4znMAI1UMCBBgJACncUlpWWQACQBXMFyE3CQAM0ZOSw8rGwckDBAWiza7fJ9C4NCkGzdOeqoFVgq44DCJN1ioJHYQAUZMAB5o2P4APgAaJErqvLqC4l9SYekx-knEVYhxoqX9FfkZudZj9mYANZbRQqNTHADkBiMJnBRyQu1S2l0pGSezSSEyahywHsSAA9HikNwASBBIVLkhRH5RORoHAngBJeb8KAQeCsRjcYBMyw5fQAeXqAFkKhgOQwIEylPw2LkngRrkUQiUIsgQVlaoVSFDjFAzL0vA4tb1XO4De1Av5LTdimFSvCUvEtHVUakMllsQMhrbwnJTjVnQ0mj1PBbOt1WK1DV6rkEffcJlMvrMYgtaO8VmsNtsEQdjv7zjHvcqwgnHsh2BVXosUpnAcDlFkITqYXCABTJn5IABkDrRAEpEgF8YT+DxOABCQoE0gAWnnC8XS+XK9Xa6X+yQAD8d7u9-vd9PCQBBPJlqboPJcjDCGuxJA1Rg-RiNfh4gCOFUwL8YEH0s9pJAAHc2CUIkYA5LlMF9ZB1lsKpUygAA6IhixGe1c2MfRO1TBIcPmHs+1Sa0lRGc8nnYF54jvD5VnrdUwSQSFDF1KBYWOTC-3wsILkGRV4C5SwLHMbjNUVUhGmaSMkAAIjKdZOEEGTDmNLoehk9huFYcYZPJXEZ2JUlUP4wSwhgcxKNeZ1jUk9TLP4ZTVIjcwNJeDlbGMIDHPEh8WJMFzIkU+pGliKQTm4CpWXzbhbCA9ZWCgbzkSSR10SsCpkBnNhRhWdLkFYJRXGeV5CpWEAUrRPSRyJEkyVjMQBOAIT0gMdgLKozgxOS2zpNcnSVJ8tTess9zPKS5EWz1FyACUuSQAB1HIoGyQRwRWEJ4ABF5lOSqqZzHKRjldeJGBWMBTqgdpjOM0hqSuPwgA)